# Rails and ES6 with Vue and JQuery code organization

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ecmascript-6

I'm refactoring my old rails app with coffeescript and I'm switching to webpacker, ES6 and Vue. I need to keep jquery, a lot of component require the library so I have some Vue component and some jquery component.

Now I'm handling:

- Global init script, jquery components that are used on every page
- Specific page script, jquery component that are used on a specific page
- Vendor bundle

For the global init script in my `app/javascript/packs/admin.js` I have

```
// init global javascript
import '../admin/global/init';
import '../admin/global/app.menu';
import '../admin/global/app.fileinput';
import '../admin/global/app.dateinput';
```

where `init.coffee` is

```
window.App ||= {}

App.init = ->
  App.fileInput.init()
  App.dateInput.init()

$(document).on "turbolinks:load", ->
  App.init()
```

And `fileinput.coffee` is something like

```
App.fileInput =
  init: ->
    $('.file .file-input').on 'change', ->
      $('.file-name').html(this.files[0].name) if this.files.length > 0
```

For page specific script I use the data attribute on the body and then

```
class Init
  constructor: ->
    page = "#{$('body').data('page')}"
    @execute_page_js(page)
  execute_page_js: (page) ->
    if 'function' is typeof window.App[page]
      klass = window.App[page]
      new klass()

$(document).on 'turbolinks:load', ->
  new Init()
```

And then a specific script for every page

```
class App.adminHomeIndex
  constructor: ->
    console.log 'test'
```

For a specific page I could have a Vue component, so in my view

```
- content_for(:javascript_packs) do
  == javascript_pack_tag 'admin/product/form', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload'
  == stylesheet_pack_tag 'admin/product/form'

#app-container
```

and in my packs

```
import Vue from 'vue/dist/vue.esm'
import ImageUpload from '../../../admin/components/ImageUpload.vue'
import Slider from '../../../admin/components/Slider.vue'

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const vueApp = new Vue({
    el: '#app-container',

    components: {
      'image-upload': ImageUpload,
      'slider': Slider
    },
  })
})
```

I'm learning ES6 and I'm looking for a way to keep the same structure switching from coffeescript to ES6.

Is possible to use the page specific pack that I use for vue components also to init a jquery component? 
I'm trying to find a good es6 code organization guide online but I cannot find any reference...

Comment: You can find a good code organisation guide for Vue here: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-class-component It uses ES6 classes to describe Vue classes, just like you do in your code. I would strongly recommend ditching jQuery, because it will directly conflict with how Vue works internally. I know it's a problem for some jQuery plugins...! In any case you shouldn't use `$(elem)` to get dom elements, just use Vue components for that. Also don't use `$(document)` to see if the DOM is ready, because Vue might not be ready. You can use Vue lifecycle functions for that.

Comment: I know how to organize code for Vue. The problem are some vendor plugin that are jquery based like the wysiwyg editor

Comment: I understand, but while refactoring it may be wise to find non-jQuery plugins for this. CKEditor, PELL or Jodit may be workable?

Comment: @Kokodoko no, my app is an editorial cms and the editor is the most important component!

Comment: But CKEditor isn't good enough? Perhaps you can create a new question that has your Vue component with your jQuery text editor. That way we can see what's going wrong and see if there is a way to integrate them.